# How to print the missing date folder in a directory using python

Tags: python

I have a below text in file: `demo.txt`  which contain date folder name in it

Need to identify the missing date folder

**Below is my date folder :**

```
20210901
20210902
20210903
20210906
20210907
20210908
20210909
202109010
202109012
202109013
202109015
202109017
202109018
202109019
```

If you observe carefully the date folder `20210904` and `20210905` and so on is missing , that folder names need to print as an output

**Expected Output:**

```
20210904 
20210905 
20210911
20210914
20210916
```

**My code :**

```
listItems=[]
f = open(demo.txt, "r")
   listItems = f.read().splitlines()

cunt=count(listItems)
   
for i in range(cunt):
    for i in list:
        if i == substr(list,1,3):
            print('present')
        else:
            print(list[i])
```

Comment: Stack Overflow won't write your code for you. Edit your question to include a good-faith attempt at meeting these requirements before posting here (as a [mre]) in accordance with [ask].

Comment: Please share your current effort and explain what is the problem. Remove the image and post text instead.

Comment: @balderman : sure just give me 5 minutes will edit it again with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over file and create [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object from every line. You can use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) with format `"%Y%m0%d"` to parse string into `datetime` object. Then you calculate difference between dates and if it's more than 1 day launch loop which will print missed dates using [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) with format `"%Y%m%d"`:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

with open("demo.txt") as f:
    prev_date = None
    for line in f:
        curr_date = datetime.strptime(line.rstrip(), "%Y%m0%d")
        if prev_date:
            for i in range(1, (curr_date - prev_date).days):
                print((prev_date + timedelta(days=i)).strftime("%Y%m%d"))
        prev_date = curr_date
```

Answer (score 1):

See below (the idea is to convert the strings to dates, find min & max, loop between min and max and find the "holes")

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

dates_str = ['20210905','20210904','20210905','20210911','20210913'] 
dates = [datetime. strptime(d, '%Y%m%d') for d in dates_str]
_min = min(dates)
_max = max(dates)
missing = []
while _min < _max:
    _min += timedelta(days=1)
    if _min not in dates:
        missing.append(_min)
print(missing)
```

output

```
[datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 6, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 12, 0, 0)]
```